# How to fix moment.js in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am using moment.js and getting this error:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or
>   ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not
>   reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date
>   formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major
>   release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments:  [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useU

In my react component I have:

```
const sortTasks = (first, second) => moment(first.endDate).diff(second.endDate);
```

The first.enddate=‘20 dec 2018’

How can I avoid this warning in the console?

Comment: add .toISOString() to the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to inform moment.js about the date format used, by providing a second parameter to the `moment` function.

The format of "20 dec 2018" is DD MMM YYYY". 
If you have both dates in the same format, you should write

```
const sortTasks = (first, second) => 
    moment(first.endDate, "DD MMM YYYY").diff(moment(second.endDate, "DD MMM YYYY"));
```

Note that the other date is also explicitly transformed to a moment, since it is expressed in a non-standard format.

You can check the details in [the moment.js documentation about parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

If you want to find out the difference expressed in days, or in e.g. years / months / days, you can use `moment.duration`. Check [the moment.js documentation about this feature](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).

E.g. to obtain the number of years, months and days between two dates, say `date1` and `date2`, we could proceed as follows (assuming `date1` is before `date2`):

```
const theDuration = moment.duration(date2, date1);
const yearsElapsed = theDuration.years();
const monthsElapsed = theDuration.months();
const daysElapsed = theDuration.days();
```

Hope it helps - Carlos

Comment: Pleasure it actually helped